# How do I send an email via AWS SES only if the recipient's server supports SMTP TLS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ses, starttls

I'm using the AWS JavaScript SDK to send emails via SES. Now I want to send data that needs to be sent encrypted. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force outbound email sent through SES to be delivered only if the recipient server supports TLS.

> Amazon SES sends messages over a TLS-protected connection (TLS version 1.0 only) by default. This method, called opportunistic TLS, means that when Amazon SES establishes an SMTP connection with a receiving mail server, Amazon SES upgrades the connection using the STARTTLS protocol if the receiving mail server supports TLS. If the receiving server does not advertise STARTTLS or if TLS negotiation fails, the connection proceeds in plaintext.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html

Comment: This answer is now obsolete, since now [you can technically require TLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/security-protocols.html#security-ses-to-receiver) on newly sent messages, but **beware - it WILL break stuff and make your messaging system RFC-incompliant**.